# Windows mount custom device?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-7

Is it possible, in Windows 7 using the Win32 API, to create a custom "device" and recieve programatic callbacks for a requested file? Like [DAEMON Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) can create a virtual CD/DVD drive, I want to create a virtual HDD that allows access an FTP server via the Windows Explorer.

Maybe comparable to FUSE on Linux.

Comment: If you want to use Windows Explorer is will be far easier to create a Windows Explorer Extension than a virtual driver. That said, there is a FUSE version for Windows, [if you can believe it](http://winfuse.sourceforge.net/)...

Comment: This is [readily available](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/), no point in learning the file system driver programming skills you'd need.

Comment: @rodrigo The SourceFource site does not contain any files, but I found the google code SVN trunk. I'll need to check out Dokan for it to get started because WinFUSE is almost not documented. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HansPassant The point is not to have the FTP accessible via the filesystem, but to implement it on my own. :)

Comment: Well, nobody is stopping you.  But learning file system driver coding is something you'll have to learn by yourself, you cannot get help with it on a Q+A site.  Read the books by Walter Oney.  The fact that this kind of utility is already available does answer your question.  Clearly it is "Yes".  Boring answer.